# Cordova/Phonegap install file to externalDataDirectory

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I am using [the cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) to read and write to files on my android device. What I would like to do is to 'install' a json file to the *cordova.file.externalDataDirectory* directory. This file will contain default settings for the application but i would like to allow users to edit these settings as well (and so can't be hidden in the apps sandbox).

I can't seem to find a way how to do this. Is it possible?

The only alternative i can think of is to install a default settings file to the apps sandbox and on app bootup copy this file to the *cordova.file.externalDataDirectory* directory. This isn't ideal but it might be the the way that i'll have to go...

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            // ...
            var blob = new Blob(['{"key":"value"}'], {type: 'text/plain'});
            fileWriter.write(blob);

        }, function(e){console.log('Error')});
```

wrapped inside:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, function(fileEntry) {
     // ...
});
```

I cannot test it now, but I hope it's useful. Check also [the filesystem api guide](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) and [this tutorial](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file).